# R Shiny app load from link throws RestoreContext error yet still works?

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

I have two Shiny apps that I'm working on, and I'd like to be able to use App 1 to generate some input to App 2(in this case a gene name). The gene name from App 1 is parsed via `shiny`'s  `parseQueryString()`, and then does whatever in regards to App 2.

To simulate App 1, I just have a simple HTML file(I got the link structure from [this webinar about bookmarking](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/introducing-bookmarkable-state-for-shiny/)):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="http://10.59.24.60:3800/quux/?_inputs_&gene=IL23R">Send to targetProfiler</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where "quux" is the name of App 2. This works perfectly fine; I click the link and am brought to App 2, and then it searches for the gene name in a database, etc. However, I get a `shiny` error message in the bottom right corner

[image: like this]

in which it reads that `shiny` thinks it failed to parse the URL param, when in fact it did.

The server code that handles this is set up like this:

```
observe({
  #make sure its first time loading app 
  if (!vals$firstLoad) {
    return (NULL)
  }

  query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
  # browser()
  # Only continues when there is gene names to be queried in the URL
  req(query[['gene']])

  # Get URL parameter
  inputText <- paste0(unique(splitByComma(query[['gene']])), collapse = ',') # Only unique terms

  #do stuff with inputText
  #...
  #...
```

Is there a way to suppress this warning/error? Or what is being done wrong that `shiny` thinks that it hasn't properly parsed the URL parameter, when in fact it has?

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarked values are encoded in a URL as JSON. `IL23R` isn't a valid JSON string without double quotes. `gene="IL23R"` should work, or also percent-encoded like `gene=%22IL23R%22`.

Comment: Please watch the webinar that I linked. The presenter says nothing about JSON, and changing the link to include double quotes or `%22`'s crashes the app. The way I wrote the link seems to work for him, so curious as to why it's throwing error for me yet still actually working.

Comment: Can you post a run-able example? Error message when the app crashes? If it's not called out explicitly, at least at 8:00, the URL example shows strings encoded with double quotes.

Comment: Not sure why presenter has them in quotes, because none of the actual examples he shows after appear to have quotes. But I've been trying to reproduce with a smaller, more basic app. It's a bit tricky, but I'll edit my question when I have it working.

Comment: The later examples seem to all use numeric input values, which are encoded in JSON as-is without quotes.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce this error in another app. The code I have in my question seems to handle it fine, no error. But in my actual app, for whatever reason, it doesn't and throws annoying error.

Comment: I think I see the issue. Shiny's bookmarked URLs use JSON-encoded values, while `shiny::parseQueryString` assumes the query string is unencoded. `gene="IL23R"` would be parsed as `"\"IL23R\""` with `parseQueryString`,
 while `gene=IL23R` would result in a parse error with bookmark restoring.