# Missing double-quotes causes URL parameter parsing error in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Restoring a bookmarked state in Shiny requires that variable values encoded in the URL are [enclosed within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536690/r-shiny-app-load-from-link-throws-restorecontext-error-yet-still-works). Facebook inserts [a FBCLID parameter](https://www.glowmetrics.com/blog/what-is-fbclid-how-to-remove-fbclid-parameter-from-google-analytics/) to all outbound URLs. However, the value of the FBCLID parameter **is not** enclosed within double quotes.

Given the following [example code](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    textInput("txt", "Enter text"),
    checkboxInput("caps", "Capitalize"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$out <- renderText({
    if (input$caps)
      toupper(input$txt)
    else
      input$txt
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

one can set the value of `txt` directly from the URL when running on localhost (" replaced here with %22 URL encoding):

`[LOCALHOST:PORT]/?_inputs_&caps=false&txt=%22foobar%22`

If the app was hosted online and one would click the following URL (the FBCLID parameter from Facebook manually added here)

`[LOCALHOST:PORT]/?_inputs_&caps=false&txt=%22foobar%22&fbclid=IwAR1LoTclh05X3Y_0esenS0F-puvVhcbwfmk6MumB4ssPxy9XfEQtEf059wE`

following parsing error is raised:

```
Error in RestoreContext initialization: Failed to parse URL parameter "fbclid"
```

The issue is that if a parameter can't be mapped to any Shiny variables but it still can be parsed, Shiny simple ignores it and restores the app using all the valid parameters. I.e. this works just fine:

`[LOCALHOST:PORT]/?_inputs_&caps=false&txt=%22foobar%22&fbclid=%22IwAR1LoTclh05X3Y_0esenS0F-puvVhcbwfmk6MumB4ssPxy9XfEQtEf059wE%22`

Parsing error, however, causes also all the valid parameters to be ignored.

Adding the double quotes to the outbound URL obviously can't be done, since Facebook inserts the FBCLID parameter automatically.

Is there a way to intercept the incoming URL and manipulate it (i.e. either by inserting the double quotes or removing the FBCLID parameter altogether) before URL parameters are parsed by Shiny? I tried adding a [`onRestore()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/onBookmark.html) observer, but apparently it does not get called when a bookmarked state is initiated.

```
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
 os       openSUSE Tumbleweed         
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Helsinki             
 date     2019-08-25                  

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 callr         3.3.1   2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 devtools      2.1.0   2019-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 digest        0.6.20  2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 fs            1.3.1   2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 httpuv        1.5.1   2019-04-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 jsonlite      1.6     2018-12-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 later         0.8.0   2019-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 mime          0.7     2019-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 packrat       0.5.0   2018-11-14 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 pkgbuild      1.0.4   2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 processx      3.4.1   2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 promises      1.0.1   2018-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.2   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 remotes       2.1.0   2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 rlang         0.4.0   2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 shiny       * 1.3.2   2019-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 testthat      2.2.1   2019-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 usethis       1.5.1   2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)

[1] /home/jlehtoma/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/3.6
[2] /usr/lib64/R/library
```